# Magento 2 complicated shopping cart rule

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I can't figure out how I can create a complicated cart discount rule I need and if it can be done.

Conditions for customers should be:

1. One specific brand called "Xbrand"
2. If customer add 2 products from "Xbrand" gets 10% discount
3. If a customer add more than 2 products from "Xbrand" gets 15% discount
4. Rule must be applied only to products from "Xbrand"
5. Must work if customer combines the "Xbrand" products with products from different brands

What I have done. I managed to solve first 3 steps with creating two different rules for cart. One for 2 products with 10% discount and one for more than 2 products with 15% discount.

My problem is when a customer combines "Xbrand" products with products from other brands. There my rules don't work.

> My rule now is:
>
> If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
>
> If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
>
> Brand Name  is  Xbrand
>
> Total Items Quantity  is  2

**Get 10% discount. This works.**

But if a customer add there a product from different brand rule breaks and don't give discount

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "Products Subselection" for you conditions (instead of "Product attribute combination" that you are using right now).

That is, make sure that the condition of your first rule looks like this:
[image]

and the condition of your second rule looks like this:

[image]

Comment: So easy! My mind didn't get there! Thank you so much!!!